# Different overloading function resolution in VS 2008/2010 and VS 2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, overloading, visual-c++-2008

I have a function with following definitions,

```
void ClassA::setLabel(int* newLabels){
  try{
    std::vector<int> labels(newLabels, newLabels + bonds.size());
    setLabel(labels);
  }
  catch(const std::exception& e){
    propogate_exception(e, "In function ClassA::setLabel(int*):");
  }
}

void ClassA::setLabel(const std::vector<int>& newLabels){
  try{
    std::set<int> labelS(&(newLabels[0]), &(newLabels[newLabels.size()]));
    if(!(bonds.size() == labelS.size())){
      throw std::runtime_error(exception_msg("Does not match."));
    }
    labels = newLabels;
  }
  catch(const std::exception& e){
    propogate_exception(e, "In function AClass::setLabel(std::vector<int>&):");
  }
}
```

And a section of the code is implemented as

```
ClassA M;
int labels[]={1,2,3,4};
M.setLabel(labels);
```

In Virtual C++ 2008 Pro and 2010 Pro, the call to `setLabel` is bound to the second definition, resulting in `vector subscript  out of range` error; while in VC ++ 2013 it is bound to to the first definition.

I would expect a consistent binding to the first definition. 
My question is:
(1) Why such different behaviors between versions of VC++? 
(2) Is there a better way to design and implement the interface to avoid such ambiguity?

Updated: I removed all my VS installations and used only VC++ 2008. Now the resolution is expected. Thanks everybody for help.

Comment: Arrays decay into pointers, but would have to be implicitly converted into a `vector`... I'd expect the `setLabel(int* )` to be the unambiguous preference.. So (1) probably VC bug.

Comment: Are you 100% sure this works differently in VS2010 ? VS2005 seems to correctly resolve the call

Comment: Both my 2008 and my 2010 use the first definition. You have either lost something essential in your approximation, or your VSes are completely broken.

Comment: @molbdnilo  I traced the exception to this function, and get different bindings for different versions. Maybe the bug is somewhere else.

Comment: @Barry Arrays convert implicitly to pointers.  But it's not a user defined conversion, so it has precedence over the conversion to `std::vector` when doing overload resolution.